# What to put instead of 'parseClaimsJws' for my JWTGenerator for my Spring Security JWT Authentication Project

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I'm currently following a youtube tutorial on how to implement Spring Boot Security JWT Authentication. I created a Java backend Spring Boot project which I will be using to authenticate users for a web app I'm creating, which will be in react. This is the link to the youtube tutorial series: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M3OHzfRmJa0&list=PL82C6-O4XrHe3sDCodw31GjXbwRdCyyuY&index=9

So far I've been replacing deprecated code with updated code that I found on Spring Security's documentation, but there is one part of the code in my JWTGenerator that I'm stuck on. Here it is (this is JWTGenerator.java inside my Security folder)

```
@Component
public class JWTGenerator {
    public String generateToken(Authentication authentication){
        String username = authentication.getName();
        Date currentDate = new Date();
        Date expireDate = new Date(currentDate.getTime() + SecurityConstants.JWT_EXPIRATION);

        String token = Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject(username)
                .setIssuedAt(new Date())
                .setExpiration(expireDate)
                .signWith(Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(SecurityConstants.JWT_SECRET.getBytes()))
                .compact();
        return token;
       


    }

    public String getUsernameFromJWT(String token){
        Claims claims = Jwts.parserBuilder()
                .setSigningKey(Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(SecurityConstants.JWT_SECRET.getBytes()))
                .parseClaimsJws(token) //this part is highlighted in red
                .getBody();
        return claims.getSubject();
    }
}
```

parseClaimsJws is a part of Jwts.parser(), which is shown to be deprecated. The documentation here: https://javadoc.io/static/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt-api/0.11.2/index.html?io/jsonwebtoken/JwtParserBuilder.html, tells me to use Jwts.parserBuilder() instead. However, I don't see a replacement for parseClaimsJws in the documentation for either Jwts.parserBuilder nor in the documentation for Jwts.parser. I'm pretty stuck as to how to fix this problem as searching up parseClaimsJws barely yields any relevant search results. Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks for reading and thank you to anyone who comments!

I tried looking up a solution in this documentation page https://javadoc.io/static/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt-api/0.11.2/index.html?io/jsonwebtoken/JwtParserBuilder.html

Under JWTParser, oddly "parseClaimsJws" and its other variants aren't marked as deprecated..is there some way to use parseClaimsJws in my code still?

Comment: im going to be sad to say that the "course" you are following sadly does not know how modern security works. Issuing JWTs straight to browsers is a huge security risk and that is why there is no such filter in spring security, but still a lot of developers spread this myth that JWTs should be used for sessions. They where never designed to be used as a session holder and lack many security features that for instance cookie sessions have and aouth2 flows like Open ID Connect.

Comment: I strongly recommend that you read up on why JWTs should not be used as sessions, and then read the Spring Security Docs and implement something like FormLogin instead.

Comment: @Toerktumlare thank you for the reply! I was wondering if tI used a JWT token (generated from google identity services in my react frontend) and sent the google-issued JWT to an endpoint on my backend which uses "formlogin", which then creates a session and session cookie, this wouldn't have the same security risk right? The JWT is not used to maintain the login state, and is only used to authenticate. Please let me know if this approach is more viable for my side project. Thank you again for helping me out !

Comment: the JWT needs to never touch the browser in any shape or form unless it is in a cookie with the httpOnly, Secured and same-site flag set. Javascript in the browser is not to be allowed to touch any token, ever. So no, your solution wont work, and please do not try to "invent" new security. Stick with the standards, standards have been created because they are vetted and are secure.

Answer (score 3):

The readme of the project explains this: https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt#reading-a-jwt

The builder needs to be constructed first, and on that object you can call the `.parseClaimsJws()` method. Though it is deprecated there, in favor of `.parseSignedClaims()`. Additionally, `.getBody()` has changed to `.getPayload()`.

So your original call:

```
Claims body = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(key).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
```

would turn into

```
Claims body = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(key).build().parseSignedClaims(token).getPayload();
```

Answer (score -1):

maybe try using `Jwts.builder()`.
it worked for me.

ex:

```
String jws = Jwts.builder()   
.setIssuer("Stormpath")   
.setSubject("msilverman")   
.claim("name", "Micah Silverman")   
.claim("scope", "admins")    
.setIssuedAt(Date.from(Instant.ofEpochSecond(1466796822L)))      
.setExpiration(Date.from(Instant.ofEpochSecond(4622470422L)))   
.signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256,TextCodec.BASE64.decode("Yn2kjibddFAWtnPJ2AFlL8WXmohJMCvigQggaEypa5E=") )   
.compact();
```